# Check for HTTP Code in fetch_json sub / save previous output for backup in Perl

Tags: json, perl, http, curl

so I have to update a perl script that goes through a json file, fetches keys called “items”, and transforms these items into perl output.

I’m a noob at Perl/coding in general, so plz bear with me. The offset variable is set as each url is iterated through. A curl command is passed to the terminal, the file is put through a "@lines" array, and in the end, whatever json data is stored in $data gets decoded and transformed. and in the blocks below (where # populate %manager_to_directs, # populate %user_to_management_chain, and # populate %manager_to_followers are commented) is where fetch_json gets called and where the hash variables get the data from the decoded json. (***Please feel free to correct me if I interpreted this code incorrectly)

There’s been a problem where the $cmd doesn’t account for the HTTP Responses every time this program is executed. I only want the results to be processed if and only if the program gets http 200 (OK) or http 204 (NO_CONTENT) because the program will run and sometimes partially refresh our json endpoint (url in curl command output from terminal below), or sometimes doesn’t even refresh at all.

All I’m assuming is that I’d probably have to import the HTTP::Response pragma and somehow pull that out of the commands being run in fetch_json, but I have no other clue where to go from there.

Would I have to update the $cmd to pull the http code? And if so, how would I interpret that in the fetch_json sub to exit the process if anything other than 200 or 204 is received?

Oh and also, how would I save the previous output from the last execution in a backup file?

Any help I can get here would be highly appreciated!

See code below:

---

Pulling this from a test run:

```
curl -o filename -w "HTTP CODE: %{http_code}\n"   --insecure       --key <YOUR KEY>    --cert <YOUR CERT>   https://xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxx.xxx.xxxxxxxxxx.com:443/api/v1/reports/active/week > http.out
```

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use JSON qw(decode_json);
use autodie qw(open close chmod unlink);
use File::Basename;
use File::Path qw(make_path rmtree);
use Cwd qw(abs_path);
use Data::Dumper;
use feature qw(state);


sub get_fetched_dir {
    return "$ENV{HOME}/tmp/mule_user_fetched";
}


# fetch from mulesoft server and save local copy
sub fetch_json {
    state $now = time();
    my ($url) = @_;
    my $dir = get_fetched_dir();
    if (!-e $dir) {
        make_path($dir);
        chmod 0700, $dir;
    }

    my ($offset) = $url =~ m{offset=(\d+)};
    if (!defined $offset) {
        $offset = 0;
    }
    $offset = sprintf ("%03d", $offset);

    my $filename = "$dir/offset${offset}.json";
    print "$filename\n";
    my @fields = stat $filename;
    my $size = $fields[7];
    my $mtime = $fields[9];
    if (!$size || !$mtime || $now-$mtime > 24*60*60) {
        my $cmd = qq(curl \\
--insecure \\
--silent \\
--key $ENV{KEY} \\
--cert $ENV{CERT} \\
$url > $filename
);
        #print $cmd;
        system($cmd);
        chmod 0700, $filename;
    }
    open my $fh, "<", $filename;
    my @lines = <$fh>;
    close $fh;
    return undef if !@lines;
    my $data;
    eval {
        $data = decode_json (join('',@lines));
    };
    if ($@) {
        unlink $filename;
        print "Bad JSON detected in $filename.\n";
        print "I have deleted $filename.\n";
        print "Please re-run script.\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    return $data;
}

die "Usage:\n KEY=key_file CERT=cert_file mule_to_jira.pl\n"
if !defined $ENV{KEY} || !defined $ENV{CERT};
print "fetching data from mulesoft\n";


# populate %manager_to_directs
my %manager_to_directs;
my %user_to_manager;
my @users;
my $url = "https://enterprise-worker-data.eip.vzbuilders.com/api/v1/reports/active/week";
while ($url && $url ne "Null") {
    my $data = fetch_json($url);
    last if !defined $data;
    $url = $data->{next};
    #print $url;
    my $items = $data->{items};
    foreach my $item (@$items) {
        my $shortId = $item->{shortId};
        my $manager = $item->{organization}{manager};
        push @users, $shortId;
        next if !$manager;
        $user_to_manager{$shortId} = $manager;
        push @{$manager_to_directs{$manager}}, $shortId;
    }
}


# populate %user_to_management_chain
# populate %manager_to_followers
my %user_to_management_chain;
my %manager_to_followers;
foreach my $user (keys %user_to_manager) {
    my $manager = $user_to_manager{$user};
    my $prev = $user;
    while ($manager && $prev ne $manager) {
        push @{$manager_to_followers{$manager}}, $user;
        push @{$user_to_management_chain{$user}}, $manager;
        $prev = $manager;
        $manager = $user_to_manager{$manager};  # manager's manager
    }
}


# write backyard.txt
open my $backyard_fh, ">", "backyard.txt";
foreach my $user (sort keys %user_to_management_chain) {
    my $chain = join ',', @{$user_to_management_chain{$user}};
    print $backyard_fh "$user:$chain\n";
}
close $backyard_fh;


# write teams.txt
open my $team_fh, ">", "teams.txt";
foreach my $user (sort @users) {
    my $followers = $manager_to_followers{$user};
    my $followers_joined = $followers ? join (',', sort @$followers) : "";
    print $team_fh "$user:$followers_joined\n";
}
close $team_fh;


my $dir = get_fetched_dir();
rmtree $dir, {safe => 1};
```

Comment: See also [Getting curl to output HTTP status code?](https://superuser.com/q/272265/278134). You could also try using [`LWP::UserAgent`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent) instead of running the external `curl` program. It returns a `$response` object that you can inspect to obtain the status code

Comment: Crossposted - https://www.reddit.com/r/perl/comments/gnn7pw/check_for_http_code_in_fetch_json_sub_save/

Comment: I'd use something like Mojolicious for this so you can play with the transaction to your heart's content. My book [Mojo Web Clients](https://leanpub.com/mojo_web_clients) has lots of examples of just this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, if you want to keep the web fetch and the Perl processing decoupled, you can modify the `curl` command so that it includes the response header in the output by adding the `-i` option. That means that the Perl will have to be modified to read and process the headers before getting to the body. A successful `http.out` will look something like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: somedomain.com
Date: <date retrieved>
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: <size of JSON>
Status: 200 OK
Maybe: More Headers
Blank: Line signals start of body

{
    JSON object here
}
```

An unsuccessful curl will have something other than 200 OK on the first line next to the HTTP/1.1, so you can tell that something went wrong.

Alternatively, you can let the Perl do the actual HTTP fetch instead of relying on curl; you can use [LWP::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent) or any of a number of other HTTP client libraries in Perl, which will give you the entire response, not just the body.

Comment: I've decided to use LWP::UserAgent to check http responses. I'll be sure to come back with feedback as soon as I get around to testing this. Thanks for the input!