# Transform data from multiple JSON endpoints/URLs in one Perl script

Tags: json, perl

So this is a continuation of my last question [Check for HTTP Code in fetch_json sub / save previous output for backup in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61925598/check-for-http-code-in-fetch-json-sub-save-previous-output-for-backup-in-perl/61938479#61938479).

My Perl script has since changed from last post:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl


use warnings;
use strict;
use LWP::UserAgent ();
use JSON qw(decode_json);
use autodie qw(open close chmod unlink);
use File::Basename;
use File::Path qw(make_path rmtree);
use Path::Tiny;
use Cwd qw(abs_path);
use Data::Dumper;
use feature qw(state);


sub get_fetched_dir {
  return "$ENV{HOME}/tmp/mule_user_fetched";
}

# fetch from mulesoft server and save local copy
sub fetch_json {
  state $now = time();
  my ($url) = @_;


  my $dir = get_fetched_dir();
  if (!-e $dir) {
    make_path($dir);
    chmod 0700, $dir;
  }

  my ($offset) = $url =~ m{offset=(\d+)};
  if (!defined $offset) {
    $offset = 0;
  }
  $offset = sprintf ("%03d", $offset);
  my $filename = "$dir/offset${offset}.json";
  print "$filename\n";

  my @fields = stat $filename;
  my $size  = $fields[7];
  my $mtime = $fields[9];
  if (!$size || !$mtime || $now-$mtime > 24*60*60) {
    my $useragent = LWP::UserAgent->new(timeout => 60);
    $useragent->env_proxy;

    my $response = $useragent->get('xxxxxxxxxx.com/api/v1/reports/active/week',
    ':content_file' => $filename);

    if ($response->code == 200 || $response->code || 204 ) {

     open my $fh, "<", $filename;
     my @lines = <$fh>;
     close $fh;
     return undef if !@lines;

     my $data;

     eval {
     $data = decode_json (join('',@lines));
    };


    open (my $original_fh, ">", "original.txt") or die "\nCan't create '$original_fh'\n";
    close $original_fh;

    open (my $backup_fh, ">", "new.txt") or die "\nCan't create '$backup_fh'\n";
    print $backup_fh "$data\n";
    $path = path("new.txt", "original.txt");
    path("new.txt")->spew({binmode => ":encoding(UTF-8)"}, $data;)  
    path("new.txt")->move("original.txt");
    close $backup_fh;

    }

    } else {
    print "Something went wrong...aborting program.\n";
    print "$response->status_line";
    exit(1);
    }
  }
if ($@) {
    unlink $filename;
    print "Bad JSON detected in $filename.\n";
    print "I have deleted $filename.\n";
    print "Please re-run script.\n";
    exit(1);
  }

  return $data;
}


die "Usage:\n  KEY=key_file CERT=cert_file mule_to_jira.pl\n"
  if !defined $ENV{KEY} || !defined $ENV{CERT};

print "fetching data from mulesoft\n";

# populate %manager_to_directs
my %manager_to_directs;
my %user_to_manager;
my @users;
my $url = "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/api/v1/reports/active/week";
while ($url && $url ne "Null") {
  my $data = fetch_json($url);
  last if !defined $data;

  $url  = $data->{next};
  #print $url;
  my $items = $data->{items};
  foreach my $item (@$items) {
    my $shortId = $item->{shortId};
    my $manager = $item->{organization}{manager};
    push @users, $shortId;
    next if !$manager;

    $user_to_manager{$shortId} = $manager;
    push @{$manager_to_directs{$manager}}, $shortId;
  }
}

# populate %user_to_management_chain
# populate %manager_to_followers
my %user_to_management_chain;
my %manager_to_followers;
foreach my $user (keys %user_to_manager) {
  my $manager = $user_to_manager{$user};
  my $prev = $user;
  while ($manager && $prev ne $manager) {
    push @{$manager_to_followers{$manager}}, $user;
    push @{$user_to_management_chain{$user}}, $manager;
    $prev = $manager;
    $manager = $user_to_manager{$manager};   # manager's manager
  }
}


# write backyard.txt
open my $backyard_fh, ">", "backyard.txt";
foreach my $user (sort keys %user_to_management_chain) {
  my $chain = join ',', @{$user_to_management_chain{$user}};
  print $backyard_fh "$user:$chain\n";
}
close $backyard_fh;

# write teams.txt
open my $team_fh, ">", "teams.txt";
foreach my $user (sort @users) {
  my $followers = $manager_to_followers{$user};
  my $followers_joined = $followers ? join (',', sort @$followers) : "";
  print $team_fh "$user:$followers_joined\n";
}
close $team_fh;



my $dir = get_fetched_dir();
rmtree $dir, {safe => 1};
```

At this part of the code:

```
 open (my $original_fh, ">", "original.txt") or die "\nCan't create '$original_fh'\n";
        close $original_fh;

        open (my $backup_fh, ">", "new.txt") or die "\nCan't create '$backup_fh'\n";
        print $backup_fh "$data\n";
        $path = path("new.txt", "original.txt");
        path("new.txt")->spew({binmode => ":encoding(UTF-8)"}, $data;)  
        path("new.txt")->move("original.txt");
        close $backup_fh;
```

I'm assuming the data transformed in the fetch_json method is written to "new.txt" and moved to "original.txt". But if I'm wrong here or if these needs correction, please advise.

But other than that, I need to figure out how to transform data from not just the one url/json endpoint noted here:

```
my $url = "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/api/v1/reports/active/week";
```

...But rather three separate JSON Endpoints/URLs in the same Perl script.

I'm not sure if that just means I'd have to change "my $url" into a @urls list containing all the endpoints and then just transforming fields unique to each endpoint. I'm sure there's a better way to do this that I just don't know about.

Again, any help I can get here will be invaluable to me.

Thanks in advance!!!

---

P.S. will be crossposting this in Reddit too for further reach. See [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/perl/comments/gomw2c/transform_data_from_multiple_json_endpointsurls/).

Comment: You'll get a lot more help if you make a very small program that demonstrates the problem. This is the same feedback that you got in Reddit. As an etiquette note, I find it really annoying when anyone asks questions in two places at the same time. If you tried one place and didn't get a result, trying somewhere else is fine. But dropping a huge chunk of code in multiple places  abuses the good nature of the people you ask to help you.